# How to get url link to the data stored in cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, hosting, cpanel

I crated api with laravel and i hosted it on shared hosting cpanel.
i also uploaded data folder to public_html.
i want to get the url to my data folder to use it in my api.
in another word how to get url link to the data folder 
(i dont want to put it in public folder since it's data)
if that is not the correct aproach please help me with the correct one.
for example : 
https://my_domain_name/data/Series/2.jpg.

```
public_html
   data
      Series
          1.jpg
          2.jpg
          3.jpg
```

to make api like this

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "F20",
    "url": "https://my_domain_name/data/Series/1.jpg",
    "created_at": "2021-12-10T07:19:06.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-12-10T07:19:06.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "F22",
    "url": "https://my_domain_name/data/Series/2.jpg",
    "created_at": "2021-12-10T07:19:07.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-12-10T07:19:07.000000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "F30",
    "url": "https://my_domain_name/data/Series/3.jpg",
    "created_at": "2021-12-10T07:19:07.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-12-10T07:19:07.000000Z"
  }
]
```

Comment: Are you asking how you can move the data folder outside of the public folder (since you say that you did put it there but then later say you don't want it there), or are you asking how to get the full URL? Please be more specific about your question.

Comment: I'm asking how to get the full URL

Comment: Before asking a question, please make sure you've done [proper research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Just google "laravel get full url" and you'll get a link to the correct place in the manual plus a bunch of other questions/answers. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#generating-urls

Comment: I want the full url to file stored in cpanel, so that i can use that url and stored in database

Comment: If the above link doesn't give you the information you need, then you need to update your question to give us way more details about your question and why the above link to get the full URL doesn't work. It's then very unclear what you mean atm. Explain the flow, show what folders you have (where is that file in relation to your Laravel application?) and what you expect to get. What do you mean by "a file stored in cpanel"? Is it stored on your website or do you have some other type of storage?

Comment: It is not about laravel it just about cpanel and database  i want to store file on cpanel and get the full url to each file then use that url on database.(how can i get url of file stored in cpanel)

Comment: Cpanel is just a server and site management tool. If you store something, you store it on the server (the same goes for your application). Not only have you tagged this question with Laravel, you also say _"I crated api with laravel"_, which is where I assume you want to use the full URLs in? The API you created in Laravel? So how is it "not about Laravel"? Otherwise, why even mention it at all? Please read my previous comment again and edit your question and include all the needed details. Without them, it's not much we can do, since your question is still very unclear.